# In how many different ways can 5 tosses of a coin yield 2 heads and 3 tails?

Tags: combinatorics

This is a combinations question correct?

So the answer is C(5,3) = 10 ways correct? As C(5,3) is equal to C(5,2) So we can think of C(5,3) as all the ways of getting 2 heads and 3 tails correct?

Or is it C(5,2) x C(5,3) = 100 ways?

Comment: Yes, there are only 5C3 ways of getting 2 heads and 3 tails out of a total of 32 possibilities of flipping 5 clubs to get result.

Answer (score 1):

No, your first one is correct. This is basically the original thing the $C(n,r)$ function is designed to count. No need to multiply two of them together.

Answer (score 0):

Think of it this way for 5 coins the total number of possiblities is $2^5$ which is 32 so the answer you got later which is 100 can not be the answer you were correctly doing it in the beginning.